# Java, file doesn't exist error even if it does, web server

Tags: java

I'm writing a basic HTTP server and one of the requirements is that server checks if requested file exists. My code below

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(lines[0]);
String command = scn.next();
String fileName = scn.next();

System.out.println("Command: " +command);
System.out.println("Resource: "+"www" +fileName);

File ifile = new File(fileName);
if( ! ifile.exists() ) {
System.out.println("file "+ fileName  + " doesn't exist");
} else {
String sizestr = "bytes in file: " + ifile.length();
System.out.println(sizestr);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I get the response that file doesn't exist even if that does. Can someone please help? Thanks !

Full code to my program below :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UselessHTTPServer05 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
ServerSocket serverSock=new ServerSocket(port);

while(true) {
  Socket conn = serverSock.accept();
  Scanner scanin = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
  String line=null;
  int nlines=0;
  String lines[] = new String[32];

  while (true) {
    line = scanin.nextLine();
if(line.length()==0) break;
lines[nlines] = line;
    nlines = nlines + 1;

  }


  for(int i=0; i<nlines; i=i+1) {
  System.out.println("line "+i+": "+lines[i]);
  }

  Scanner scn = new Scanner(lines[0]);
  String command = scn.next();
  String fileName = scn.next();

  System.out.println("Command: " +command);
  System.out.println("Resource: "+"www" +fileName);

   String webRoot = "/www";
   File f = new File(webRoot, fileName);
  if( ! f.exists() ) {
      System.out.println("file "+ f.getCanonicalPath() + " doesn't exist"); }
  else {
  String sizestr = "bytes in file: " + fileName;
  System.out.println(sizestr);
  }




  String reply="HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
               "\r\n" +
               "<h1>Sorry, work in progress</h1>\r\n";


  OutputStream outs = conn.getOutputStream();
  outs.write(reply.getBytes());

  conn.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Double check your classpath. I'm sure your file is in the wrong directory. You could test this by creating a new file programmatically and try to read this file. Then check the path of your newly created file.

Comment: what is example string value of `fileName`,d where you have those files located and where from you trying to access them?? you are doing it via Java Web Project with servlets ore something more advanced? Without answers to that questions, best response you can get here is "Not enough data". Remember, that if you have your files somewhere in project, then accessing it is bit tricky.

Comment: I placed them in a subdirectory , also tried to place them in the same directory as my program.

I'm writing the code using emacs text editor on linux.

Comment: "but the file exists" you hear that frequently in this kind question and in 99% of them it is not true. Either the file path is wrong, the file name contains unexpected white spaces or an unexpected file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your output message to include a call [`File.getCanonicalPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) that way you can tell exactly where it's trying to read from;

```
System.out.println("file " + ifile.getCanonicalPath()  + " doesn't exist");
```

You should probably be constructing your `File` with [`File(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that way you can set a "webRoot" first,

```
String webRoot = "/some/directory"; 
File ifile = new File(webRoot, fileName);
```

Comment: After adding getCanonicalPath() and String webRoot. I could see that it tries to read the file from the correct folder. It still doesn't find it.

Comment: @MikeyD The file it's trying to read exists, and it has permission to read it? Are you sure? Are you *really* sure?

Comment: You have a folder "/www" on your hard drive?

Comment: Okay, problem solved. I am complete a moron, ealier it couldn't find because I did not specify the path. Now after adding String webRoot it wouldn't find it because I wrote "/www" instead of "www".After getting rid of / it found the file. Thanks for help and sorry for wasting time !

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to add a check for the file being under the directory you expect. Otherwise, relative paths might "escape" like `../../../../../../../../quicken/quicken.qif`